# How to get data from Object Oriented Programming to mySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

How I can pass the data from object oriented programming to mysql in python? Do I need to make connection in every class?

Update:

This is my object orinted

```
class AttentionDataPoint(DataPoint):
    def __init__ (self, _dataValueBytes):
        DataPoint._init_(self, _dataValueBytes)
        self.attentionValue=self._dataValueBytes[0]

    def __str__(self):
        if(self.attentionValue):
            return "Attention Level: " + str(self.attentionValue)

class MeditationDataPoint(DataPoint):
    def __init__ (self, _dataValueBytes):
        DataPoint._init_(self, _dataValueBytes)
        self.meditationValue=self._dataValueBytes[0]

    def __str__(self):
        if(self.meditationValue):
            return "Meditation Level: " + str(self.meditationValue)
```

And I try to get the data to mysql using this coding.

```
import time
import smtplib
import datetime
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.101", "fyp", "123456", "system")
cur = db.cursor()

while True:
    Meditation_Level = meditationValue()
    Attention_Level = attentionValue()
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, Meditation_Level, Attention_Level, current_time) VALUES ('test1', %s, %s, %s)"
    data = (Meditation_Level, Attention_Level, current_time)
    cur.execute(sql, data)
db.commit()

db.close()
```

Update:

DataPoint

```
class DataPoint:
def __init__(self, dataValueBytes):
self._dataValueBytes = dataValueBytes
```

Comment: You can reuse your connection (and you should), of course. Please show your codes.

Comment: @Raptor I already update the code.

Comment: what is the definition of DataPoint?

Comment: @olivecoder I already update the DataPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of something like a class that has a function for connection and you just pass the instance of that class to every class where you need the connection (here the db instance), or may be not! 
It's just an idea that I used in a other languages.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- Implement a save/load method for each DataPoint child to build the select/insert/update sql commands according with the needs of each class. Here is a basic tutorial: [Python MySQL Database Access](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm)
- Implement a class to build the sql commands above automatically from your class attributes.
- The above is called Object Relational Mapping and, so, you don't need to reinvent the wheel: https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html

I'd go with the first if it is a simple project with no chance to become big and with an ORM tool for all the other cases.

The most popular for python is SQLAlchemy: 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

Comment: It just a simple project. So I think I will use the first option. Do you have any tutorial that could help me?